# Puppeteer How to check if the page has redirected

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to check with `waitForNavigation()` to see if the page switches or not.
Here is the code I am using

```js
if ((await page.waitForNavigation()) == null) {
  console.log("False");
  await browser.close();
} else {
  console.log("True");
  await browser.close();
}
```

For example, let us just say a box on the screen is there and you get redirected to another page. I want `True` or `False` to pop up on the `console.log`.

I had to switch up the answer a bit but here it is

```js
if (newUrl == startingURL) {
  console.log("False");
  await browser.close();
} else {
  console.log("True");
  await browser.close();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only care about redirects, like HTTP redirects & `window.location.href` redirects, you can check the URL that you end up on and compare it to the URL you started with:

```
const startURL = 'https://example.com/redirect-start'
await page.goto(startURL)
if (page.url() === startURL) { console.log('False') }
else { console.log('True') }
```